# list comprehension functions in python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, reduce

There are the map,reduce,filter functions to make list comprehensions.

What is the difference between passing a `xrange` argument or a `range` argument to each of these functions?
For example:

```
map(someFunc, range(1,11))
```

OR

```
map(someFunc,xrange(1,11))
```

Comment: Ask separate questions rather than vaguely related questions. You will get better answers.

Comment: @WaleedKhan OK, I'll remove the second question from here :)

Comment: The answers to these questions depend on the version of python you're using, FYI.

Comment: @JoelCornett Oh, I didn't know that. Well, I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: [List comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) are an (often better) way of producing a list with similar functionality to ``map()`` and ``filter()`` but with a syntax which is usually significantly more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, `range` returns an actual list, while `xrange` returns a generating function which can be iterated over. Since `map` only cares that it iterates over a sequence, both are applicable, though `xrange` uses less memory. Python 3's `xrange` replaces `range`, so your only option is to use `range` to return a generating function. (You can use `[i for i in range(10)]` to generate the actual range if so desired.)

<strike>The modulus operator returns `0`, a falsey value, for the even numbers: 2 mod 2 is 0. As such, the even numbers are filtered out.</strike>

Comment: Then there will be no difference whether I call these functions with xrange or with range?

Comment: The end result will be the same, but `xrange` will do it with less resources.

Comment: And as you said, in python 3 the range function becomes the xrange?
So in fact, there is no python 2.7 range in python 3? (function that creates a list).

Comment: @Lior No, but you can use a list comprehension as stated. You can also use `list(range(10))` for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `map`, `reduce`, and `filter` functions are an *alternative* to list comprehensions.  The term "list comprehension" refers to the specific syntactic construct; anything that doesn't look like a list comprehension is necessarily not a list comprehension.

They actually predate list comprehensions, and are borrowed from other languages.  But most of those languages have ways of constructing anonymous functions which are more powerful than Python's `lambda`, so functions such as these are more natural.  List comprehensions are considered a more natural fit to Python.

The difference between `range` and `xrange` is that `range` actually constructs a list containing the numbers that form the range, whereas an `xrange` is an object that knows its endpoints and can iterate over itself without ever actually constructing the full list of values in memory.  `xrange(1,1000)` takes up no more space than `xrange(1,5)`, whereas `range(1,1000)` generates a 999-element list.

Answer (score 2):

If `range()` and `xrange()` were implemented in the Python language, they would look something like this:

```
def xrange(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None: stop, start = start, 0
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step

def range(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None: stop, start = start, 0
    acc, i = [], start
    while i < stop:
        acc.append(i)
        i += step
    return acc
```

As you can see, `range()` creates a list and returns it, while `xrange()` lazily generates the values in a range on demand. This has the advantage that the overhead for creating a list is avoided in `xrange()`, since it doesn't store the values or create a list object. For most instances, there is no difference in the end result.

One obvious difference is that `xrange()` doesn't support slicing:

```
>>> range(10)[2:5]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> xrange(10)[2:5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
>>>
```

It does, however support indexing:

```
>>> xrange(11)[10]
10
```

Comment: @Lior: No problem. I realized that it came a bit late (Waleed's answer is great), but I had already almost finished writing my answer at that point :p